# Varying negative voltage from a switching regulator

Tags: switching-regulator, digital-potentiometer

[image]I've looked up switching regulators with inverting configurations that can give a varied output by setting feedback resistance. Now I want to vary this voltage through a uC.
I didn't find any digital potentiometer which would accept negative voltages at the resistance terminals.
What are the possible circuits I can try?

Comment: Welcome! Freely variable or a few fix steps?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you use a fixed resistor and a DAC to inject current from the positive rail?  Basically set FB to the minimum negative voltage and then push it more negative by applying 0-3.3V to the other side of the resistor?

Comment: Have you heard of power supply margining controllers?

Comment: I want freely variable. Input is 5-5.5V and required output is 0.8-4V. I'm not sure I understand the DAC solution. Will check out power supply margining but I'm hoping those solutions are compatible with negative voltages.